# find out hardware requirement before installation jupyter

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

The jupyter installation instructions (https://jupyter.org/install) does not show hardware requirements.

Does anyone know, to consider before trying to install?

Comment: Before using Anaconda, ask yourself a few of these questions.  Why use Anaconda?  Anaconda places a layer of unknown between the user and the software.  Most experienced users won't use Aconda.  Anaconda requires up to 2 gigabytes of hard drive memory and includes many packages most people don't want or use.  If you are only using python and R, then there is no reason to use Aconda.  Do yourself a favor and learn how to install common software packages.  Then learn how to use pip for package management.  It's easy to find answers to questions about python, Jupyter, R, ...) but not Aconda.

Answer (score 2):

I've found several hardware requirements that might be of help.

If using Jupyter Notebooks as part of [Anaconda Enterprise 4 Notebooks](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda-enterprise/system-requirements/):

```
AEN Server
    RAM: 2+ GB
    CPU: 2+ cores
    Storage: 20 GB
AEN Gateway
    RAM: 2 GB
    CPU: 2 cores
    Storage: 3 MB (minimal storage required)
AEN Project Nodes (N-machines)
    RAM: 2 GB
    CPU: 2 cores
    Storage: 3 GB/project
```

Or from [here](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/sfire-dsc/6.5.0/doc/html/TIB_sfire-dsc_sys-req/GUID-291ABBD3-9DC6-4659-8595-3F208F24565A.html) if using Jupyter Notebooks with Team Studio:

```
Memory and disk space required per user: 512MB RAM + 1GB of disk + .5 CPU core.
Server overhead: 2-4GB or 10% system overhead (whatever is larger), .5 CPU cores, 10GB disk space.
Port requirements: Port 8000.
```

Generally, as you can see not much is needed and most systems should be able to run without a problem - e.g. I've had success running Jupyter Notebooks on a Raspberry Pi Zero with following specs:

```
1GHz single-core CPU
512MB RAM
```